# Add an entry to recycle bin right click menu using C#

Tags: c#, contextmenu, windows-shell, right-click, recycle-bin

I'm looking for a C# code to add my own entry to recycle bin right click menu.
I've already seen [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/SimpleContextMenu.aspx). What should i do to represent recycle bin.(Sample is provided for jpeg files)

Comment: Please tell me what to use instead of "Jpegfile".
And don't ask me to use "Folder".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your registry entries under HKCR\CLSID{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shell. The GUID you see there is the CLSID for the Recycle Bin COM object.